# Group data based on dates to populate a Material Angular table with rowspans

Tags: javascript, angular-2+

I have this method that attaches the year and year's rowspan for a TD and Quarter and a Quarter's rowspan for the TD.

Year and Quarter are 2 columns in an Angular Material Table which are calculated from an array of objects one of which property of the object is a date string.

Here is a demo for the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynpmdk

> 

**This is my method which works fine, I wanted to review if I can shorten this method, looks very ugly. Open to suggestions.**

```
/**
 * Gets the year/quarter span information and filters what data is to be shown in tabs
 * @param data launch data all
 * @param mode which tab we are on
 */
getGroupData(data: DATA[]) {
  data.sort((a:DATA, b:DATA) =>
    !a.date ? -1
      : !b.date
        ? -1 : (new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime())
  );
  let cYear = data[0];
  let cQuarter = data[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].date) {
      const curDate = new Date(data[i].date);
      const dateYear = new Date(cYear.date);
      const dateQuarter = new Date(cQuarter.date);

      // Get Year span and Year values
      data[i].year = curDate.getFullYear();
      cYear.year = dateYear.getFullYear();
      if (cYear.year === data[i].year) {
        cYear.yearSpan = (cYear.yearSpan || 0) + 1;
      } else {
        cYear = data[i];
        cYear.yearSpan = 1;
      }
      // Get Quarter span and Quarter values
      data[i].quarter = this.getQuarter(curDate.getMonth());
      cQuarter.quarter = this.getQuarter(dateQuarter.getMonth());
      if (cQuarter.quarter === data[i].quarter) {
        cQuarter.quarterSpan = (cQuarter.quarterSpan || 0) + 1;
      } else {
        cQuarter = data[i];
        cQuarter.quarterSpan = 1;
      }
    } else {
      cYear = cQuarter = data[i];
      cYear.yearSpan = cYear.quarterSpan = 1;
      cYear.year = cYear.quarter = 'TBD';
      if (i === data.length - 1) {
        break;
      } else {
        cYear = cQuarter = data[i + 1];
      }
    }
  }
  return data;
}

/**
 * Get the quarter info from month index
 * @param month month index
 */
private getQuarter(month: number): string {
  return `Q${Math.ceil((month + 1) / 3)}`;
}
```

A sample data object looks like

```
{position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', date: '2016-01-11', symbol: 'H'}
```

when the method is invoked the record becomes

```
{
  position: 1, 
  name: 'Hydrogen', 
  date: '2016-01-11', 
  symbol: 'H', 
  year: 2016, 
  quarter: 'Q1', 
  yearSpan: 5, // The other records have 5 entries pertaining to this year
  quarterSpan: 2, // The other records have 2 entries pertaining to this quarter of this year
}
```

Here is a demo for the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynpmdk?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts